# VS auto-generated class error: Type already contains definition

Tags: c#, visual-studio, auto-generate

I have the following class generated with Visual Studio's "Paste JSON as classes":

```
namespace MTGCollectionTracker
{

    public class ScryfallCardSource
    {
        //long chunk of code
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string lang { get; set; }
        public string released_at { get; set; }
        public string uri { get; set; }
        //another long chunk of code
    }
}
```

I get two "Type already contains definition" errors for `set_name` and `set_uri`. Why do I get them and how do I fix them?

Comment: try renaming the variables name and uri inside your class and check if you face the same errors

Comment: You probably have 2 properties called name and uri. `set_xxxx` is the internally generated method name for the setter for property `xxxx`.

Comment: Can you show the original json you pasted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why do you get them:
   You have two class members that have the same name
2. How do you fix them:
   Rename one of them

Comment: Thanks. I literally had a property `set` and a property `set_name`. Think it's kinda funny

Comment: Hi, @Vavřinec Kubíček. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.